# turn an array of (scalar) functions into a function returning an array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, function, numpy

I have an array `farr` of functions, say

```
import numpy as np
farr=np.array([(lambda x, y: x+y) for n in range(5)])
```

(in reality, the functions are all different splines)
Now, I would like one function `f` that returns the result of all the functions in `farr` as an array. Basically this:

```
def f(x, y):
    return np.array([f(x, y) for f in farr])
```

Can this be done in a more efficient way?

Comment: and what did you get with this code ? What result did you expect? Use some example data to show expected result.

Comment: @furas my code works, but I wonder if this is the most efficient way

Comment: If `farr` is a list instead of an array it should iterate a bit faster.

Comment: `frompyfunc` often provides a modest improvement over iteration (up to 2x). 
 A possible use: `fn=np.frompyfunc(lambda f,x,y:f(x,y),3,1)`, and `fn(farr[:,None],x,y)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way is to use map:

```
x = 3
y = 3
value = list(map(lambda f: f(x,y), farr))
```

For more details see [map doc](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html).
On my machine this is a tiny bit more efficient (~20% faster)

Comment: I like this. Typically, I think of mapping a function over some value, but here I "map the values" over some functions.